# USB-to-CAN not working but reported as working

Tags: linux

I'm using an USB-to-CAN-Udapter on RasparryPi. Everything seems good and CANsend is also reflected in CANdump.

State seems to be fine according to `ip -details -statistic link show can0` as well:

```
    <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP
    mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can promiscuity 0 minmtu 0 maxmtu 0
    can state ERROR-ACTIVE restart-ms 100
```

Also CanDump does not show the messages from the BUS (I know there are some). During CANsend also the TX led is no flashing. Seems like the connection is not really established to the Hardware.

If I connect the USB-to-CAN-Adapter directly to my PC I can see the CAN-Frames and also send, so the wiring should be fine.

What I checked:

- Checked the CAN-Wiring: Fine.
- Checked the state of the CAN-Interface: Reported as fine
- Checked CANdump during CANsend: working